# install sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, installation, sharepoint-2010

I need to learn sharepoint, for that i need to install it also!. hence let me know what does it take to install it. i guess there are 2 enviornments : Dev & production.Am i correct?

Resources that i have with me is;

1. windows 7 64bit home premium (laptop)
2. windows 7 32bit professional (desktop)

let me know if any info required.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation Requirements: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4

Installation Guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx

Evaluation Guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262881.aspx